# How to check if a custom field has specific value

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a new post (type event) every time one of my posts is updated and custom_field has the value 'ja'.
I don't understand why the if query  if($customfield == 'ja'){}
doesn't work.

```
function create_event($post_id, $post, $post_before){
if (get_post_type($post) == 'product') {
    $customfield=get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_field');
    if ($customfield == 'ja') { //this if query doesn't work
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $event = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'post_title' => get_the_author_meta('firmenname', $author),
            'meta_input' => array('post_id' => $post_id, '_EventStartDate' => '2019-06-04 00:00', '_EventEndDate' => '2019-06-04 23:59',
                'test'=>$customfield)
        );
        wp_insert_post($event);
    }
}
add action('post_updated', 'create_event', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function create_event($post_id, $post, $post_before){
if (get_post_type($post) == 'product') {
    $customfield=get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_field', true);
    if ($customfield == 'ja') { //this if query doesn't work
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $event = array(
            'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
            'post_title' => get_the_author_meta('firmenname', $author),
            'meta_input' => array('post_id' => $post_id, '_EventStartDate' => '2019-06-04 00:00', '_EventEndDate' => '2019-06-04 23:59',
                'test'=>$customfield)
        );
        wp_insert_post($event);
    }
}
add action('post_updated', 'create_event', 10, 3);
```

to get value in variable you need to write this 
`$customfield=get_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_field', true);`